# Unit test kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing

This is viewModel class.

```kotlin
    @HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: InquiryRepositoryImpl,
) : ViewModel() {

    // LiveData to hold the list of inquiries
    private val _inquiryResult = MutableLiveData<List<Inquiry?>>()
    val inquiryResult: LiveData<List<Inquiry?>> get() = _inquiryResult

    // LiveData to control the visibility of progress dialog
    private val _isProgressDialogVisible = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isProgressDialogVisible get() = _isProgressDialogVisible

    /**
     * Fetches inquiries data from the repository for the specified user NIC.
     * Shows a progress dialog while fetching data.
     * Dismisses the progress dialog after data fetching is complete.
     * @param createdUserNIC the NIC of the user for whom inquiries are to be fetched
     */
    fun fetchData(createdUserNIC: String) {

        // Show progress dialog
        isProgressDialogVisible.value = true

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

                val response = repository.getInquiriesByFarmer(createdUserNIC)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    val inquiry = response.body()
                    _inquiryResult.value = inquiry?.data

                    delay(2000)
                    // Dismiss progress dialog after data fetching is complete
                    isProgressDialogVisible.value = false

                } else {

                    Log.e("HomeViewModel", "Error: ${response.code()}, ${response.message()}")
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                // Handle exceptions
                e.printStackTrace()

            }

        }

    }

}
```

And this is Test class.

```kotlin
    @RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class HomeViewModelTest {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var inquiryRepository: InquiryRepositoryImpl

    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        // Initialize ViewModel with mocked repositories
        viewModel = HomeViewModel(inquiryRepository)
    }
    @Test
    fun `testFetchDataSuccess`() {
        val dummyNIC = "911111111v"
        val mockInquiries = listOf(
            Inquiry("userNIC1", "https://example.com/image1.jpg", "Problem 1", "2024-02-07", "1")
            // Add more mock inquiries if needed
        )
        runBlocking {

            val serverResponse = Response.success(ServerResponse(data = mockInquiries, "Data fetched Successfully", true))
          `when`(inquiryRepository.getInquiriesByFarmer(dummyNIC)).thenReturn(serverResponse)

            viewModel.fetchData(dummyNIC)

           

        }
    }
```

It is getting this error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Cannot mock/spy class repository.InquiryRepositoryImpl
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class.
```

I added the all the dependencies

Comment: Try to use and mock the interface, not the implementation (InquiryRepository instead InquireRepositoryImpl).